# Error on I-94 (TN worker)

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens, i-94

I am a Canadian on TN-1 status, living in Metro Detroit.

I got my TN in June 2017 with an expiry date of June 2020. When I first received my TN, I got a correct I-94. When I briefly flew out of the US for a trip in November, I got a correct I-94 upon re-entry.

I drove to Windsor, Ontario this morning and returned the same day. I used the Nexus lane for both trips (my Nexus card is linked to my TN). I showed my November I-94 to the US CBP guard on my way back.

When I went to check my new I94 on the website, to my shock it said my class of admission is F-1 with an "admit until" date of "D/S". Even stranger is that the "record number" is identical to the record number issued on my I-94 from July 2016, when I was indeed on F-1 (I was a student from July 2016 to May 2017). It looks like the computer system glitched big time, since if the CBP guard had entered my admission class incorrectly, I should have still received a new "record number".

Is this something to worry about? Should I waste an hour driving to Detroit Airport to get this resolved?

Comment: I don't have an opinion on the worth of going to the airport but I have seen that website print odd I-94s after land border crossings before. I don't know if it is the entry with no exit record, the AVR entry or something else that confuses the website printer, but my bet is if you go to the airport they'll tell you that you are still in TN status and all is fine (though I don't know that for sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in F-1 status you're not allowed to work, so given how seriously the US takes immigration violations, you ***definitely*** need to go to the deferred inspection site at the airport (open Mon-Fri 10AM-6PM) to get it resolved.

Bring an I-94 printout and the travel document (either your passport or NEXUS card) whose document number is stated on the I-94